# I intend to create an infinity for loop but it came out with a result

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
    int x , sum = 0;
    for (x = 10; x > 0; x++) {
        sum += x;
    }
```

> I am expecting the loop never end because x will never hit 0.

```
    System.out.println(sum);
```

> It surprises me when it outputs this value -1073741869 , where my x is incrementing instead of decrementing.

Comment: You are overflowing. You incremented over the max int value.

Comment: I see.Thank you!